# Disable TLS <1.2 with Spring Boot (embedded Tomcat Server) + Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, heroku, salesforce, tls1.2

I'm trying to disable TLS <1.2 (so disable TLS 1.0 & 1.1) on my Spring boot (v. 1.4) app which is running on Heroku.

This app integrates with Salesforce so for security reasons the app (which is an outside website) should not accept TLS connections that are <1.2.

Since the Spring Boot version is 1.4, it really should be as simple as adding a few lines of code to the application.properties file OR the yaml. And, I have tried this in almost every combination.

For example, I currently have the following in my yaml:

```
Spring:  
  server:
    ssl:
      enabled: true
      protocol: TLS
      enabled-Protocols: [TLSv1.2]
```

The application builds fine on Heroku and is up and running, but it still accepts TLS 1.0 and 1.1 connections (confirmed via https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test), and I really do not understand why.

I'm trying to determine if this is something related to Heroku. They do manage certificates automatically via what they call ACM. And with ACM you are not able to disable certain versions of TLS. But, my understanding would be that it shouldn't matter, if I'm telling the embedded Tomcat (Spring Boot) server to only accept TLS 1.2 connections, then the Heroku server should actually come after that and hence follow the same rules.

Just to add all of the information I have: server.error.whitelabel.enabled = false is in the application.properties file. This is the only server setting in that file, but I'm just adding in case maybe applications.properties file could interfere with the yaml? (even though I have tried removing it and it did not fix the issue).

So, why is my app / website still accepting TLS <1.2 connections??

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It depends on how you're using Heroku. See https://help.heroku.com/G0YVUNPG/how-do-i-disable-support-for-tls-1-0-or-1-1-on-a-heroku-app for details.

Comment: Did you find solution for this ? I want tot do the same thing.